# Distinct values in python list

Tags: python, list, unique

I need to extract unique values in python list by omitting the repeated values altogether:

**Input:**

```
lis = ['a','l','f','a']
```

**Desired Output:**

```
lis2 = ['l','f']
```

So I need to remove all duplicate iteams.
Sets won't do cause I don't want 'a' in it

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: `[x for x in lis if lis.count(x) == 1]`

Answer (score 1):

You basically want items which count in the list is only 1. Count of items in the list - [use `Counter` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
lis = ['a','l','f','a']
counter = Counter(lis)
lis2 = [elem for elem in lis if counter[elem] == 1]
print(lis2)
```

You could also use `list.count`, but that would go through the list each time, giving you `O(n^2)` complexity, while creating the Counter is `O(n)` and then checking count is `O(1)` (n times), resulting in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner to make it simple!

```
lis2 = list(set(lis) - set([x for x in lis if lis.count(x) > 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

this little function will create a dictionary of the number of occurrences of each element, then filter out the ones with multiple occurrences, and return the resulting list.

```
lst = ['a','b', 'c', 'a']

def removeDupes(lst):
    counts = {}
    for item in lst:
        if counts.get(item):
            counts[item] += 1
        else:
            counts[item] = 1
    result = dict({(k, v) for k, v in counts.items() if v == 1})
    return result.keys()

print(removeDupes(lst)) # outputs: ['b', 'c']
```

Comment: Yo, you're reinventing the wheel. :P https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter - Counter already creates the dictionary you want. Also, by doing `.items()`, creating the dict with comprehension and they getting its `.keys()`, you're doing a lot of overhead work. ;)

Comment: You're 100% right, I didn't know about the Counter class. Need to brush up on the collections module.